# Highlight the css cards upon search in angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have array of items which are rendered on UI as angular material cards. I have a search box where user input for items. once the search is implemented I get the searchItems as another array. Now I want to highlight (changing the background color of the card or a rectangular animation) items array angular material cards which are matched with searched items. I was stuck at implementing this css part although I am able to render and match the items with searchdItems

```
 <div *ngIf="searchedItems">
      <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" *ngIf="searchedItems.length === 0">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times </a>
        <strong>{{data.value}}</strong> not found
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="searchedItems.length > 0" class='searchitem'>
        {{data.value}} found in
        <div *ngFor="let item of searchedItems; let i = index">
          {{item}} {{i}}
        </div>


      </div>

    </div>

    <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="100px">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items; let x = index">
          <mat-grid-tile [ngClass]="item.name == item ? 'searchexample-card': 'example-card'" routerLink="/inventory/items/{{item.name}}">
            <mat-card>
              <mat-card-header>
                <b>Item{{item.name}}</b>
              </mat-card-header>
            </mat-card>
          </mat-grid-tile>
        </div>

      </mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: That was the one I tried but ideally i don't want the search items in a separate div. I just want to highlight the items (mat-grid-list ) cards which are matched with searchItems

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking maybe put up a stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsi6aq. If you see here, i have items array ['INDIA', 'USA', 'RUSSIA', 'UK', 'ITALY'] and on UI respective css cards are shown, once the user enters item value and click the search, the new serachedItems array would be created with ['INDIA', 'USA'];. Now on UI i have to highlight INDIA and USA cards of items array as those are in items array. I am stuck at comparing the items values with serachedItems so that i can highlight the item cards. This should be done when search button is clicked and if serachedItems  atleast one value   (*ngIf = serachedItems>0)

Comment: did the solution worked for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't implement this soultion as I can't modify my items list as suggested with labeling, i have items of 1000 records and i am looking for alternate solutions. I have already implemented pipe on  data to get searchedItems and now i have to highlight the css cards of items by comparing items vs sreachedItems.

Comment: np check the new answer. Hope this is what you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unable to change the items array I have modified the answer for the pipe which will not impact your original array

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'highlight', pure: false
})
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any, filtered?: any[]): any {
    let newArray = [];
    if(Array.isArray(items) && Array.isArray(filtered)) {
      for(let item of items){
        newArray.push({label: item, highlight: filtered.indexOf(item)>-1})
      }
    } else {
      newArray = items.map(item => ({label: item}));
    }
    console.log(newArray)
    return newArray;
  }

}
```

But your html template will be modified to accommodate the highlight

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | highlight: searchedItems" [ngClass]="{card: true, highlight: item.highlight}">
  {{item.label}}
</div>
```

Here I am passing the array that you have after you search `searchedItems` to my highlight Pipe

Hope this answers your question

Updated Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oyhva7

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the condition that you have implemented for activating [ngClass]. You are comparing an object with object property, this comparison for **item** with **item.name** will always return false.

consider you have the searched result in **searchedItems[]** array. Now you want to highlight those items in the loop of whole items. then your code should be something like this

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of items; let x = index">
    <mat-grid-tile [ngClass]="item in searchedItems ? 'searchexample-card': 'example-card'">
        <mat-card>
           <mat-card-header>
              <b>Item{{item.name}}</b>
          </mat-card-header>
       </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
 </div>
```

> Considering your items array and searchedItems[] is of same type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a pipe from Angular

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'highlight',
  pure: false
})
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any, search: string, clip: boolean): any {
    const regex = new RegExp(search, 'ig');
    if(Array.isArray(items) && search) {
      for(let item of items) {
          item.highlight = regex.test(item.label);
      }
    }
    return clip ? items.filter(item => item.highlight) : items;
  }
}
```

I have passed in the search term in the pipe and the full array always returning from the pipe, but using a regular expression or maybe your custom logic of search add another attribute to the list item `highlight` boolean which is true if your logic says it matches the item, else false

I have modified the items array from `string[]` to `{label:string, highlight?:boolean}[]` to accommodate the pipe change so instead we are using the array as

```
items: {label:string, highlight?:boolean}[] = [
  {label: 'INDIA'},
  {label: 'USA'},
  {label: 'RUSSIA'},
  {label: 'UK'},
  {label: 'ITALY'},
];
```

Now to all put it into the template

```
<div 
  *ngFor="let item of items | highlight: search" 
  [ngClass]="{highlight: item.highlight, card: true}"
>
  {{item.label}}
</div>
```

Here when you search, if it matches with any of the item from items array will have a `highlight:true` attribute as true and also adds a class called 'highlight` to your existing div.card so in css defining the highlight card as

```
.card.highlight{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Notice that we are sending the search term to the pipe that we created as an argument, so we have to define the variable as a class level variable which is set when we click search in your method devicesearch which you are already calling.

```
search: string;

devicesearch(input) {
  this.search = input;
}
```

**Edit 2:**

If you wanted the clipped array you can use the Pipe in your class to get the clipped array

```
search: string;
searchedItems: any[];
highlightPipe = new HighlightPipe();

devicesearch(input) {
  this.search = input;
  this.searchedItems = this.highlightPipe.transform(this.items, input, true);
  // only names --> const names = this.searchedItems.map(item => item.label);
}
```

Updated StackBlitz for your reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-usswkn

Comment: Thanks for your detailed code. Actually my use case is that  when the button is clicked I get the searchedItems array  (could be one value or more) which should be compared with items array. Then if the searchedItems are matched with items array, i need to highlight the items array css card stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsi6aq.

Comment: that's how angular recommends it. If you want to get only matched items you can call the pipe from app.component. check the updated code.